# Positioning image absolutely in bootstrap navbar list item without effecting nav height?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, list, nav

### This question has been solved, but I can't accept answers on my own question for another two days yet for some reason?

I've got a justified bootstrap nav that needs to have an image for one of it's items, my problem is that I can do this but the height of the nav shifts to match that of the image, but I need the nav to remain around 50px high and for the image to more or less overlay the nav - example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/2vp56uta/

I tried making a div within the list item to act as a container for the image, be positioned relatively and give it a fixed width the same width as the image but list items go over the image:

HTML

```
<div class="logo-nav">  
    <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placecage.com/c/141/141" alt="">
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.logo-nav {
    position: relative;
    width: 141px;
}
.logo-nav a {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/2vp56uta/1/

I can't see why the list items following won't take into account the width of the container .logo-nav?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry I mustn't have explained it very well, I wanted the image to be 100% width and height with the nav sitting behind it. Having said that though I solved it using a margin instead of a width, which pushes over the list item after it to the right.

```
.logo-nav {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 141px;
}
.logo-nav a {
    margin-right: 1px;
}
.logo-nav img {
    position: absolute;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x3rsy53d/3/

Markup just needs cleaning up and to made more efficient now :)!

Thanks for your answers everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want it something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/2vp56uta/2/

Thanks to the CSS3 background property you can solve this problem quite easy. But if you want to place lots of different images in your page I'd suggest you better look for a different solution.

```
<li><a id="img" href="#"></a></li>

#img {
background:url('http://placecage.com/c/141/141')no-repeat center;
background-size:contain;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood what you're trying to accomplish (I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "overlay"), [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/2vp56uta/3/) seems like it will do that you want.

```
.logo-nav {
  height: 50px;
}

.logo-nav a img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

The issue with the way you are trying to do it is that `position: absolute` takes an element out of the layout flow, causing the page to layout like that element wasn't there.